# 2GP push error modify managed object

Tags: managed-package, package, 2gp

i have the following error when i want to push a 2GP in a new Scrach org
force-app\main\default\objects\Country__mdt\fields\Country_Code__c.field-meta.xml      Cannot modify managed object: entity=CustomFieldDefinition, component=00N5400000OQTkx, state=MANAGED_RELEASED, Field: OptionsFlag OptionBit: OptionsFlagRequired Previous Value: true New Value: null (10:9)

and the same code appears for 8 custom field ...
here the custom field :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CustomField xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <fullName>Country_Code__c</fullName>
    <externalId>false</externalId>
    <fieldManageability>DeveloperControlled</fieldManageability>
    <label>Country Code</label>
    <length>3</length>
    <required>true</required>
    <type>Text</type>
    <unique>false</unique>
</CustomField>
```

i see in our git i didn't change the value of required is always true ...

If someone can help me ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is currently a [Known Issue](https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p4V000001U7sTQAS). There is no feasible resolution you can undertake. It's related to Custom Fields on Custom Metadata Types.

My understanding, as of 2021-07-26, is that this issue is likely to be patched in the next few days. I am a Salesforce employee but am not on the team working on this issue; this is not an official statement or commitment. Safe Harbor applies.

Comment: thanks you , really good job ....