# cannot push code to scratch org because of error related to managed object

Tags: salesforcedx, managed-package, salesforcedx-cli

all

From last week, we run into some issue that our DX build cannot push code to a scratch org for below errors.

```
Error  force-app/main/default/objects/AAMeta__mdt/fields/VVVV__c.field-meta.xml            Cannot modify managed object: entity=CustomFieldDefinition, component=00NR000000IIaVh, state=MANAGED_RELEASED, Field: OptionsFlag OptionBit: OptionsFlagRequired Previous Value: false New Value: null (7:13)
Error  force-app/main/default/objects/AAMeta__mdt/fields/AAAFields__c.field-meta.xml  Cannot modify managed object: entity=CustomFieldDefinition, component=00NR000000IIaVj, state=MANAGED_RELEASED, Field: OptionsFlag OptionBit: OptionsFlagRequired Previous Value: false New Value: null (19:13)
Error  force-app/main/default/objects/AAMeta__mdt/fields/BBBB.field-meta.xml              Cannot modify managed object: entity=CustomFieldDefinition, component=00NR000000IIaVl, state=MANAGED_RELEASED, Field: OptionsFlag OptionBit: OptionsFlagRequired Previous Value: false New Value: null (30:13)
```

After some search,  I though it might related to ancestorId in project setting, but after I removed ancestorId, I still cannot push code to scratch org.

We never pushed code to this scratch org before, so really cannot understand where does this MANAGED_RELEASED state come from?

Is there someone run into same issue, or someone had some experience on it?

Thanks

Comment: It just happened last week, we started to create managed package created some weeks ago.

We changed field recently, but it shouldn't impact on scratch org at all, should only impact on package because of upgrade.

Comment: Not an answer, but when I hit issues with push and don't have time to find out why I tend to just use `sfdx force:source:deploy` with the `-p` option to specify exactly what I want to put into the scratch org.

Comment: The trigger is different, but this seems highly likely to be related to [this problem (and Known Issue)](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/350502/2gp-push-error-modify-managed-object/350503#350503).

Comment: @stanley, as David pointed out it's likely related to this known issue. We have this known issue and were able to push to Scratches after removing ancestorId from `sfdx-project.json`, maybe try creating a new scratch and push then

Comment: by the way David, it does seem that Known Issue it not fully described, because you also can't push your existing sources to Scratch Orgs created after this issue was introduced. Is it possible to suggest changes?

Comment: as an addition here is linked [sfdx-cli issue](https://github.com/forcedotcom/cli/issues/1088) moderator was able to push by removing `ancestorId`

Comment: I resolved issue by removing ancestorId when creating scratch org.

Also there is a known issue https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p4V000001U7sTQAS which seems fixed already.

We are fine now, thanks all.